# Power Query - Retain Number Formats

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I am very new to using Power Query and I am sort of confused as to if its possible to retain number formats when importing a table. I have a table of around 30 columns that I am importing via Power Query, however, all the number formats change after the table is imported to the sheet. Is there a way to avoid this and retain the source number formats?

Comment: Did this answer solve your issue? If so please, accept it to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2):

Usually after importing a table, powerquery auto generates a Change Type step where it sets the column types to what it thinks you should have. You can hit the X to remove that step, in the box off toward the right, resetting format to default

[image]